# How to add HTML tags inside the existing HTML page?

Tags: java, html, parsing

I have a skeleton XHTML page. I want to read the other HTML file and get the body part from that file and I want to add that whole body part into the existing (X)HTML file. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Do I go with any parsing like techniques to achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Since you said it is XHTML You can just use any XML parser like SAX or DOM and treat it as XML. I suggest looking into groovy XML slurper as well my personal favorite.

Comment: Please be very clear on the fact that HTML & XHTML are different formats.  I edited your question to try and underline that this problem deals with 2 different document types.  Please review the changes carefully.  Further, while XHTML might conceivably be parsed using XML based APIs like DOM, the HTML cannot.  For the HTML you'll need something more like JSoup or Entagged.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DOM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) api.  You can get an element in one page by its id or tag and then call [appendChild](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) to add an element from the other page.